# Select multiple meta_values from MySQL meta table based on common meta_key using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Meta data tables (e.g. wp_postmeta) have a number of different keys and values each contained within separate rows but each associated with the same post ID.

I want to create a single array for each post_id that contains each of the meta_values and meta_keys in an associative array using a query.

**What I have tried**

```
$orderdetails = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT meta1.post_id
     , meta1.meta_value AS Company
     , meta2.meta_value AS Volunteers
     , meta3.meta_value AS Date
     , meta4.meta_value AS City
     , meta5.meta_value AS Created
  FROM wp2_postmeta meta1
     , wp2_postmeta meta2
     , wp2_postmeta meta3
     , wp2_postmeta meta4
     , wp2_postmeta meta5
 WHERE meta1.meta_key LIKE '_billing_company'
   AND meta1.meta_value = '$order_company'
   AND meta2.meta_key LIKE 'additional_volunteers'
   AND meta2.post_id = meta1.post_id
   AND meta3.meta_key LIKE '_paid_date'
   AND meta3.post_id = meta1.post_id
   AND meta4.meta_key LIKE '_billing_city'
   AND meta4.post_id = meta1.post_id
   AND meta5.meta_key LIKE '_created_via'
   AND meta5.post_id = meta1.post_id
", OBJECT_K);
```

**Why I'd like to improve on this**

The query above does work, but seems inelegant because it is long and references the same table separately for each meta_value. Any thoughts on how I can improve it are much appreciated.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Brian. I will look at this.

Comment: This isn't inelegant

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without all the joins using pivot syntax.

```
SELECT post_id, 
    '$order_company' AS Company,
    MAX(IF(meta_key = 'additional_volunteers', meta_value, '')) AS Volunteers,
    MAX(IF(meta_key = '_paid_date', meta_value, '')) AS Date,
    ...
FROM wp2_postmeta
WHERE post_id = (SELECT post_id FROM wp2_postmeta
                 WHERE meta_key = '_billing_company'
                   AND meta_value = '$order_company')
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. It doesn't seem to work for me though. Is it missing some close brackets at the end of the MAX statements?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle demonstrating the problem?